Java Clipboard content paste to browser on Ubuntu 24.04.1
I try to paste content to Firefox with Java 17 Robot on Ubuntu 24.04 with the following code:
                entry = dataStore.getEntry(lstHosts.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

                Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
                StringSelection strSel = new StringSelection(entry.get(cbxUserName.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()));
                clipboard.setContents(strSel, null);

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

I use Netbeans 22 to develop this JavaFX project.
When I'm on Netbeans, the content passed well to the editor. But I can't paste content to any Ubuntu component (LibreOffice Writer, TextEditor or Firefox brower). I tried with SHIFT + INSERT and JDK11 with same result. On Kubuntu 24.04, Ubuntu 22.04, Windows 10 and Windows 11 works fine. How can I solve this problem?
Thanks for suggestions!
